# Prove $\frac{x+1}{\sqrt{x^5+x+1}}+\frac{y+1}{\sqrt{y^5+y+1}}+\frac{z+1}{\sqrt{z^5+z+1}}\ge 3$ for positive $x^2+y^2+z^2=x+y+z$.

Tags: inequality, problem-solving

I need your help to solve this Math Olympiad problem:
**Let $x$, $y$ and $z$ be positive real numbers such that  $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = x + y + z$.**

**Prove that :**
$$
\frac{x+1}{\sqrt{x^5+x+1}}+\frac{y+1}{\sqrt{y^5+y+1}}+\frac{z+1}{\sqrt{z^5+z+1}}\ge 3
$$
*In order to solve that problem*: I tried to prove that each fraction in the inequality is > or equal to 1 in the given case.
So I factored the denominator of the expression:
$$
\frac{x+1}{\sqrt{x^5+x+1}}
$$
To make it equal to:
$$
\sqrt{(x^2+x+1)(x^3-x^2+1)}\
$$
Then I used this relation:
$$
\sqrt{ab} \le \frac{a + b}{2}
$$
To conclude that:
$$
\frac{x+1}{\sqrt{(x^2+x+1)(x^3-x^2+1)}} \ge \frac{2x + 2}{x^3+x+2}
$$
The problem I faced is that I did not know how to link the given information that was presented to the result that I reached, and I do not really know if what I did was useful. In the end, I think I tried enough, and I need the opinions of those who are more knowledgeable than me. I would be grateful if someone could help me find a solution, thanks in advance.

Comment: Another way to try your approach would be to see if $\dfrac{x+1}{\sqrt{x^5+x+1}}\geqslant 1+k\cdot(x-x^2)$ for some suitable $k$, this brings the condition into play, and boosts your attempt to show each term exceeds $1$. It turns out scaling factors near $k = \frac12, \frac13$ etc. work just fine.

Comment: Side note that the assumption of $ (x+1) / \sqrt{ x^5 + x + 1 } \geq 1 $ is too naive. EG it doesn't hold for when $ x = y \approx 1.366, z = 0.5$.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, although I know that not every fraction must be greater than 1, but that was a momentary thought, and the solution was not based on it in its entirety. We are trying to improve.

Comment: Please credit the Math Olympiad source where you saw this, and be specific.  See https://math.stackexchange.com/help/referencing.  Also, why is this inequality relevant and useful to future users of this site?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're almost there.  Note $(x+1) \mid (x^3+x+2)$, so we have
$$\frac{2x+2}{x^3+x+2} = \frac2{x^2-x+2}$$

Now looking at the denominator's $x^2-x$ term should remind you of the constraint; and [CS inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality#Sedrakyan%27s_lemma_-_Positive_real_numbers) gives:
$$2\sum_{cyc}\frac1{x^2-x+2} \geqslant 2\cdot\frac{9}{6+\sum_{cyc}(x^2-x)}=3$$